# KVM reports strange CPU usage peaks (bash infinite recursion)

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, cpu, kvm

On a KVM machine running Fedora 20 I ran `ulimit -s unlimited` (this removes limit on stack size) and an experimental <strike>torturing</strike> testing script.  All this script does is just infinite recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn() {
    true
    fn
}

fn
```

What I expected was that CPU usage would go to 100%, and after some resource depletion (which could take long time), the bash would be eventually shot down by kernel.

But what really happened is somewhat strange and I don't have the right knowledge to explain:

- Inside the VM, top reports 100% CPU usage by this funny script.  That
  makes sense.
- But from outside, virt-manager shows 0% no CPU usage, expect for recurring
  sharp 100% peaks.  And as if that was not strange enough, the delay
  observed between each consecutive peaks is growing (eventually the delay
  stops growing and becomes coinstant):

[image: CPU usage peaks]

Why is this?  What is actually happening inside?  Or is the usage reported by virt-manager misleading?  Then what creates the pattern seen between the peaks?

Answer (score 1):

If you use top inside the virtual machine you noticed the cpu usage about 100%, but in you physical host the virtual machine can't use the all cpu time, this is because a kvm vm is normal normal process from the kernel point of view, so kernel process scheduler share the cpu with other process